# How to automate form filling with tkinter selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, web-testing, webautomation

How can I loop through each text in tkinter entry box and use selenium to fill website forms with the data in my entry widgets? I have managed to do so but it works only if I have one text in each entry widget. I want to add for example more order numbers and automate the form filling. Here is the code and the GUI that I made:
[image]

Code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
root=tk.Tk()
HEIGHT=300
WIDTH=500


POkeyword_list=StringVar()
SW1keyword_list=StringVar()
SW2keyword_list=StringVar()


def chromeO():
    os.startfile(r'C:Users\me\Desktop\SeleniumChrome')
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.debugger_address = "ip:port"
    bot=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    url = "link"
    PO=POentry.get()
    bot.get(url + PO)
    time.sleep(2)
    editheader = bot.find_element_by_name("editHeaderButton").click()
    SW1=str((StartSW_entry.get()))
    SW2=str((EndSW_entry.get()))
    time.sleep(2)
    startswbox = bot.find_element_by_name("earliestShipDate").clear()
    startswbox = bot.find_element_by_name("earliestShipDate").send_keys(SW1)
    endswbox= bot.find_element_by_name("latestShipDate").clear()
    endswbox = bot.find_element_by_name("latestShipDate").send_keys(SW2)
    time.sleep(1)
    savebtn=bot.find_element_by_name("saveButton__").click()
    popup=bot.switch_to_alert().accept()


#Create label, entry box and click button
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()
root.title('Ship Window Butler') #Program Title
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/me/Documents/Python Projects/WebTest/Butler1.ico") #Program icon
#Create background image
background_image=tk.PhotoImage(file='Code_presentation_background.png')
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

#Create Order number
POlabel=tk.Label(root, text="Order number")
POlabel.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.2,anchor="n")
POentry = tk.Entry(root, bg="white",textvariable=POkeyword_list)
POentry.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.3,anchor="n")
#Create click button
Submitbutton=tk.Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda:chromeO())
Submitbutton.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.8, anchor="n")


#Create Action1 box
StartSW_label=Label(root, text="Action 1")
StartSW_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor="n")
StartSW_entry=Entry(root, bg="white",textvariable=SW1keyword_list)
StartSW_entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor="n")



#Create Action 2 box
EndSW_label=Label(root, text="Action 2")
EndSW_label.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.2, anchor="n")
EndSW_entry=Entry(root, bg="white",textvariable=SW2keyword_list)
EndSW_entry.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.3, anchor="n")



def test():
    print((POkeyword_list.get()).split(" "))
    print((SW1keyword_list.get()).split(" "))
    print((SW2keyword_list.get()).split(" "))




button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda:test())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: be more clear please'

Comment: The question is specific. The program I wrote opens a webpage and fills a form in that webpage with the data written in the textboxes. What is needed next is to add more text in the widgets and automate webform filling. Webdriver will take first item from the widget, finish form filling, then will loop thru the next item.

Comment: So you every time you fill out the text boxes, you want the web-driver to fill out a form with the text from those text boxes?

Comment: After I press the click button of course, I gave the command. The program works only if there is one string in each text boxes, I want it to make it work by picking first string, upload, then get the next string. The strings are comma separated.